# AWS - Added Layers are not listed and available in lambdas

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a Cloud9 instance with a virtual python environment, what is going to published as a layer. Until today it was possible to zip the env libs and publish it to make it available in lambda functions. (= Standard workflow).

Command (as usual, execution was possible without errors):

```
aws lambda publish-layer-version --layer-name MyLayerName --zip-file fileb://python.zip --compatible-runtimes python3.9
```

But...

```
aws lambda list-layers
```

delivers an empty array. It also not selectable as a custom layer in my lambdas.

Does anybody has an explanation for this issue?

Best,
Felix

Comment: Do you receive any errors? Have you changed the configuration of your AWS cli? Is it accidentally go to the wrong account?

Comment: is the lambda having the correct Environment? because a lambda for Node 16.X will not have layers which are configured for Node 14.x etc

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. The layer had a size >250 MB.

I found this out after I tried to import it as a ZIP via the web interface. An error message came up. There is no error message on the console...